# Midlet doesnt respond to touch in older touch screen phone

Tags: java-me, midp, touchscreen, cldc, samsung-mobile

I am very new to j2me. I have developed a basic SMS Banking app. My app works in most phones which are touch and non touch devices (Samsung duos, Monte, Nokia 6120c …, Sony Ericson w300). But when I installed it in a Samsung SGH-D980 it installs and starts fine. But the list element which is the first screen after my loading splash screen does not respond to the touch. I have developed the app using Net beans 7.0.1 and uses CLDC 1.0 and MIDP 2.0. I have tried the defaultfxtouchphone emulator and works fine on it too. My problem is why does it work on some touch phones but not in the above mentioned touch phone. thank you,

Comment: are you using any kind of GUI , like J2ME Polish ?

Comment: Are you loading the list element in `startApp()`?

Comment: Did you try to download Samsung Java SDK 1.2.2(http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/down/cnts/toolSDK.detail.view.do?platformId=3&cntsId=7985&nacode=) and see if you can get this device connected in debug mode with your IDE. However I only did this on Sony Ericsson devices that been reasonable easy to connect through SE dev tools

Answer (score 1):

The fact that touch events are available to MIDlet at any other phones means nothing in your case.

MIDP specification ([JSR 118](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=118)) does not force implementation to make touch (pointer) events available to MIDlets even for touch device. According to [data provided at club-java page](http://www.club-java.com/TastePhone/J2ME/MIDP_Java_telephone.jsp?m=1137&brand=Samsung&model=SGH-D980), this is exactly the case for SGH-D980:

> Touch screen or mouse (hasPointerEvents()) **No**
>   Stylus motion events (HasPointerMotionEvents()) **No**

As soon as device allows to work with your list in non-touch fashion (you wrote nothing that says it ain't so), there is no problem - you just have to live with that.

> of course not passing touch events to MIDlets when these are available natively means that MIDP implementation on this device sucks. But that's a different story